# Exception name for db locked

Tags: telethon

What is the except name for database locked? I have tryed with:

```
        client=TelegramClient(session, api_id, api_hash)
        client.connect()
    except Exception:
        print("Session already in use")
        return
```

but sometimes it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

It is `sqlite3.OperationalError`.

Comment: so i write: ```except sqlite3.OperationalError: ```?

Comment: Yes, that is what you write. Make sure you `import sqlite3` before.